Issues with loading screen on Wordpress
I have taken over for. a previous developer.
I'm looking for help on our word press site. I can't seem to find an issue that when you click any new page or refresh I get a loading bug. Here is the site https://www.thelearningcode.com/
I have tried to add preloader plugin but the issue persists

Look at the site with Dev Tools, which are available in any browser: https://www.codecademy.com/article/use-devtools
I see Javascript console errors having to do with a cache and a minify plugin; try deactivating any cache or minify plugins.
